# Discord.js argument Loop not picking from array

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

Hi im pretty new to loops as ive been trying to get some to work after watching some tutorials but i keep getting it looping over the entire array rather then stopping when the args match

```js
    let user = message.author.username
    let itemName = "betakey";
    let opt = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    let array = ['info', 'special', 'flex', 'default']
    
    if(opt[0])
    
    for (a in array){

        if (array[a] === 'info'){
            message.channel.send(`info`);
            break
        }
        if (array[a] === 'special'){
            message.channel.send('special')
            break
        }
        if(array[a] === 'flex'){

            message.channel.send('flex')
            break
        }
        if(array[a] === 'default'){
            message.channel.send('>betauser info | special | flex')
            break


        }

    }else{
        message.channel.send('error')
    }
    console.log(array[a])
    

}
```

any help appreciated

Comment: Did you try -> for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) instead of for (a in array) ? Could it be because of this?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to accomplish. The `for (a in array)` works for me and stops once an if statement kicks in.

Comment: also, you seem to have some issues with your curly brackets.

Comment: Fix your braces, log your values and see what is returning unexpected

Answer (score 0):

Problem:
Curly braces were not correct,you need to use for of, you were referencing a as if it was the index but in reality, it is the current item.

Therefore here is the correct code:

```
let user = message.author.username
let itemName = "betakey";
let opt = args.shift().toLowerCase()

let array = ['info', 'special', 'flex', 'default']

if(opt[0]){

for (a of array){

    if (a === 'info'){
        message.channel.send(`info`);
        break
    }
    if (a === 'special'){
        message.channel.send('special')
        break
    }
    if(a === 'flex'){

        message.channel.send('flex')
        break
    }
    if(a === 'default'){
        message.channel.send('>betauser info | special | flex')
        break


    }
}
}

}else{
    message.channel.send('error')
}
console.log(a)
```

For more info here is a post from w3schools about it see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_forof.asp.